# Nginx + Php-Fpm = 404

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, http-status-code-404, fpm

Digital Ocean Ubuntu 18.04 VPS running Nginx 1.17.10 + PHP-FPM 7.3. I am unable to figure out how to properly run PHP files (everything else runs fine.) The php files produce Nginx's 404 not found page. Nginx error log only shows "signal process started." I restart nginx + fpm after every change. I have looked at practically every StackOverflow question related to this and have tried all sorts of variations of configurations. I would appreciate any input on this situation. (domain names and IPs are changed to example.com and 127.0.0.1 for sake of anonymity.)

**Nginx Server Config:**

```
server {
            listen 80;
            listen [::]:80;
            root /example.io/public;
            server_name www.example.com example.com;
            return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
            index index.html index.php;
    }
    server {
            listen 443 ssl;
            ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
            ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
            ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
            ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

            location / {
                    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
                    proxy_http_version 1.1;
                    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    add_header Front-End_Https on;

    }
            location ~ \.php$ {
                    include /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.3-fpm.sock;
            }

            location ~ /\.ht {
                            deny all;
            }
    }
```

**/etc/nginx/conf.d**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
        limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/s;
        map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        ''      close;
#       limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/s;


        }

#       upstream websocket {
#       ip_hash;
#       server 127.0.0.1:8081;
#       }
        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

#       ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
#       ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

#       include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

**Fastcgi-php.conf**

```
# regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

# Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

# Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
# see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi.conf;
```

**Fastcgi_params**

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $request_filename;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      /example.io/public;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

**php.ini**

Default php.ini file for php fpm 7.3 except for this change I made (uncommented it):

```
cgi.fix_pathinfo=1
```

**www.conf**

Included the main portion of it. Anything not included is default.

```
; Start a new pool named 'www'.
; the variable $pool can be used in any directive and will be replaced by the
; pool name ('www' here)
[www]

; Per pool prefix
; It only applies on the following directives:
; - 'access.log'
; - 'slowlog'
; - 'listen' (unixsocket)
; - 'chroot'
; - 'chdir'
; - 'php_values'
; - 'php_admin_values'
; When not set, the global prefix (or /usr) applies instead.
; Note: This directive can also be relative to the global prefix.
; Default Value: none
;prefix = /path/to/pools/$pool

; Unix user/group of processes
; Note: The user is mandatory. If the group is not set, the default user's group
;       will be used.
user = www-data
group = www-data

; The address on which to accept FastCGI requests.
; Valid syntaxes are:
;   'ip.add.re.ss:port'    - to listen on a TCP socket to a specific IPv4 address on
;                            a specific port;
;   '[ip:6:addr:ess]:port' - to listen on a TCP socket to a specific IPv6 address on
;                            a specific port;
;   'port'                 - to listen on a TCP socket to all addresses
;                            (IPv6 and IPv4-mapped) on a specific port;
;   '/path/to/unix/socket' - to listen on a unix socket.
; Note: This value is mandatory.
listen = /var/run/php7.3-fpm.sock

; Set listen(2) backlog.
; Default Value: 511 (-1 on FreeBSD and OpenBSD)
;listen.backlog = 511

; Set permissions for unix socket, if one is used. In Linux, read/write
; permissions must be set in order to allow connections from a web server. Many
; BSD-derived systems allow connections regardless of permissions.
; Default Values: user and group are set as the running user
;                 mode is set to 0660
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
;listen.mode = 0666
; When POSIX Access Control Lists are supported you can set them using
; these options, value is a comma separated list of user/group names.
; When set, listen.owner and listen.group are ignored
;listen.acl_users =
;listen.acl_groups =
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering, I started over with a fresh VPS and installed everything perfectly and all that and it fixed it. I must have been messing with configuration and those types of things too much with the above setup.